# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript

I try to display a popup when I click on a button using javascript.
But this error appears :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: confirmation is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

```js
function confirmation() {
  var answer = confirm("Leave tizag.com?")
  if (answer) {
    alert("Bye bye!")
    window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
  } else {
    alert("Thanks for sticking around!")
  }
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" class="danger btn btn-danger" onclick="confirmation()">Transférer</button>
```

Comment: your code working file...

Comment: Your code is working..check your snippet

Comment: That code works just fine. My suspicion is that you were trying to do this in jsFiddle. jsFiddle has a truly brain-dead^H^H^H^H^H^H I mean, *surprising* default setting: It wraps all your code in a `window.onload = function() { /*...*/ };` wrapper. The old `onxyz`-attribute style event handlers can only call global functions (it's one of several reasons not to use them). When jsFiddle wraps your code like that, your function isn't a global. Click the [JavaScript] label on the code pane to change the default, but really it's better to use modern event handling in the first place.

Comment: This still not work with me ! maybe because I try to integrate javascript code in template angular 2 !

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a solution that will work for sure.

Add an event listener of DOMContentLoaded to the whole document and call an anonymous function.
You can then wrap your code in that function's brackets
and it will execute once loading is complete.

```
<button type="submit" class="danger btn btn-danger" >Transférer</button>

<script>
 var btn = document.querySelectorAll("button")
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    btn[0].addEventListener("click", function () {

// When this button is clicked we want to enable zooming of our list.

// To do this we add an event listener to our list itself,
// so when the cursor hovers it, the enlarge function gets called.
    var answer = confirm("Leave tizag.com?")
      if (answer) {
        alert("Bye bye!")
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
      } else {
        alert("Thanks for sticking around!")
      }

});
});
</script>
```

have a good day :)

Answer (score -1):

You may haven't linked your `.js` file with your `.html` file. That's the only possible problem.

At the end of your html `<body>` tag add a:

```
<script src="your-script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you place your javascript code to a script block? i.e

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirmation() {
      var answer = confirm("Leave tizag.com?")
      if (answer) {
        alert("Bye bye!")
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
      } else {
        alert("Thanks for sticking around!")
      }
    }
</script>
<button type="submit" class="danger btn btn-danger" onclick="confirmation()">Transférer</button>
```